# Thurston's and Morgan-Shalen's compactifications of Teichmuller space

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let ${\cal T}(S)$ be the Teichmuller space of a hyperbolic surface $S$ of finite volume. Let $\cal S$ be homotopy classes of simple closed curves in $S$. Thurston compactified ${\cal T}(S)$ by taking the closure of the image of 
$$L: {\cal T}(S)\to \mathbb P^\cal S,\quad L(\sigma)=(l_\sigma(\gamma))_{\gamma\in \cal S},$$
where $l_\sigma(\gamma)$ is the length of the geodesic representative of $\gamma$ in the metric $\sigma.$
Morgan-Shalen compactified ${\cal T}(S)$ by taking the closure of the image of 
$$\theta: {\cal T}(S)\to \mathbb P^\cal S,\quad \theta(\sigma)=(log(|tr(\sigma(\gamma))|+2))_{\gamma\in \cal S},$$ 
where ${\cal T}(S)$ is identified with a connected component of the $SL(2,\mathbb R)$-character variety of $S$.

Why are these compactifications the same? 
J.-P. Otal in ``Compactifications of Spaces of Representations after Culler, Morgan, and Shalen'' says that it is implied by the fact that there are $c_1,c_2>0$ such that 
$$c_1\cdot l_\sigma(\gamma)\leq log(|tr(\sigma(\gamma))|+2)\leq c_2\cdot l_\sigma(\gamma),$$
for every $\sigma, \gamma.$ But I don't see how this inequality implies the equality of compactifications.

Comment: When you ask for them to be "the same" presumably you mean homeomorphic?

Comment: At the least, "sameness" of these compactifications has to be stated carefully, because obviously the embeddings $L$ and $\theta$ are not "the same". I think the correct statement should be that the homeomorphism $L(\mathcal{T}(S)) \to \theta(\mathcal{T}(S))$ induced by the identity map on $\mathcal{T}(S)$ extends to a homeomorphism of closures
$$\overline{L(\mathcal{T}(S))} \to \overline{\theta(\mathcal{T}(S)})
$$ 
which restricts to the identity map on the points of 
$$\overline{L(\mathcal{T}(S))} - L(\mathcal{T}(S)) = \overline{\theta(\mathcal{T}(S))} - \theta(\mathcal{T}(S))
$$

Comment: Otal's reason is not a good one. One can give a better, additive, inequality: $|\theta- \frac{1}{2}L|\le 3$. Now, replace $L$ with $L/2$ (which is projectively the same) and everything becomes clear.